# Use new ase file to change multiple files created with old ase file and global colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-conversion, swatches, adobe-library

I have 30 files all colored using the same global color swatch palette generated by the same .ase color swatch library. Is there a way to use a new .ase file to globally change those colors? I know that you can import new swatches and use them to replace the old swatches on a file by file basis, but maybe there is a way to change the colors globally for all 30 files at once. InDesign allows for global style updates so maybe Illustrator does too. Perhaps there is a way to just update a global color palette across all 30 files instead.